# Github и использование тегов

Tags: github, git-commit

Здравствуйте.
Присутствует у меня некое непонимание тегов в Git.
Опишу ситуацию.
Есть некий проект Project. Делаю коммит, пуш с тегом 1.0 . Добавляю на packagist, все отлично отображается dev-master, 1.0 . 
Захотелось мне внести некие изменения в версию 1.0. Тег уже создан, делаю новый коммит и пуш, но все изменения вносятся в dev-master.
Почему так?
Заранее спасибо.

Comment: Потому что теги не ветки и сидят там, где созданы.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Тег - это просто именованный коммит.
Если нужно поддерживать несколько версий делай ветки.
Т. е. в твоём случае сделай ветку начинающуюся с тега 1.0 туда и вноси правки для этой версии.

**Обновление**

Т. к. тег - это просто имя коммита, то никаких изменений в нём не сделаешь. А в какую ветку коммитить и как организовывать - тебе решать. Вот, например, начало списка веток из репы `scrapy`:

```
  remotes/origin/0.12
  remotes/origin/0.14
  remotes/origin/0.16
  remotes/origin/0.18
  remotes/origin/0.20
  remotes/origin/0.22
  remotes/origin/0.24
  remotes/origin/1.0
  remotes/origin/1.1
  remotes/origin/HEAD -> origin/master
```

Т. е. они каждую версию ведут в своей ветке.

Comment: А когда мы добавляем зависимость в require секцию, например
require: {
    "project": 1.0
}
1.0 - чему соответствует? Ветке? Тегу? Тегу в главной ветке?

Comment: А когда будет версия 1.1 снова ветку создавать?
Если взять популярные репозитории, к примеру, Yii2 у них все организовано тегами.
То есть они перед пушем создают тег с новой версией и делают пуш? И далее если делаются какие-нибудь изменения они уже будут в новой версии. 
Я правильно понял?

Comment: А когда мы добавляем зависимость в require секцию, например require: { "project": 1.0 } 1.0 - Откуда берется версия? Где ее можно изменить, что бы packagist знал. И что бы устанавливалась последняя стабильная.
Не приходилось писать "регулярных выражений" в версии - ^1.0-dev
А - 1.0 или 1.1 или 1.1.2